# Python distribution statistics on scatter plot style data

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, histogram, distribution

I'm trying to get statistics on a distribution but all the libraries I've seen require the input to be in histogram style. That is, with a huge long array of numbers like what `plt.hist` wants as an input.

I have the bar chart equivalent, i.e. 2 arrays; one with the x-axis centre points, and one with y-axis values for the corresponding value of each point. The plot looks like this:

[image: Bar chart of raindrop diameter frequency in 5 minutes]

My question is how can I apply statistics such as mean, range, skewness and kurtosis on this dataset. The numbers are not always integers. It seems very inefficient to force python to make a histogram style array with, for example, 180x 0.125's, 570x 0.25's e.t.c. as in the figure above.

Doing mean on the current array I have will give me the average frequency of all sizes, i.e. plotting a horizontal line on the figure above. I'd like a vertical line to show the average, as if it were a distribution.

Feels like there should be an easy solution! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's straightforward to compute statistics from binned data. The general idea is to construct an approximate probability density function from the bins, and then compute mean, variance, etc. from the approximate density. The simplest approximation is to just take the histogram bins and normalize them so that the area under the curve is 1. Use the definition of mean, etc., which is appropriate for the pdf. E.g. mean = integral of x times pdf(x); that will be a summation when you're working with the normalized histogram. There might be functions to carry out these operations, I don't know.

Comment: I fear that doing but explicitly would be quite computationally expensive as I have to repeat it about 700,000 times for a single result! (I have 9 months of 1-minute rainfall data and want the difference in mean, skewness e.t.c. of the distribution per minute) I was hoping there is a way to use the built in functions but somehow tell it that you have already binned the data yourself which I assume is the first step of the SciPy functions.

Comment: My guess is that whatever computer you are using is capable of easily handling the 700,000 data, without binning or any other kind of summary; that's not a large data set these days. My advice is to try directly computing the quantities you want on the whole data set and see if that's fast enough. If you are unsure, you can try subsets (let's say, increasing multiples of 7000) to see how the computation time increases with the size of the data set, and judge whether you can handle the whole data set.